# How to change or swap value in relation with one column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have a table with two column x and y without any index or primary key fig:1.0 as shown bellow:

[image]

I want to change the values of y like:

```
x1 = y2
x2 = y1
x3 = y4
x4 = y3
x5 = y6
x6 = y5
```

Pattern will be like this:

[image]

Output will look like this:

[image: output image]

How do I do this using select query? If not possible with Select then how to do with Update or any other way in MySQL.

Comment: Is there something to determine the order? I see that there are duplicate values in the column x.

Comment: Column X will remain same but the value of Y will Shift/Swap.

Comment: *"How do I do this using select query?"* Not possible with the current data example as there is not a order in SQL tables..

Comment: can we do it with UPDATE query ? or any other way in MySql

Comment: No like i said there is not order in the data example, so in cases of "ties" in this case 12 for x column MySQL does not know which record should be "first" or "last".. Even when you use `ORDER BY x` the order for "ties" is still random..

Comment: The logic and the expected output do not seem to match. After x1 = y2 I would expect the first row to be 22, 21, not 11, 22. Also, an sql table is not a spreadsheet. The records do not have an intrinsic order. You need to specify how to order the records. This task seems to be better suited to an application, not to sql.

Comment: *"The records do not have an intrinsic order. You need to specify how to order the records. "* indeed @Shadow but even when you use `ORDER BY x` the order for "ties" is still random

Comment: @RaymondNijland the combination of x-y values seem to be unique.

Comment: values may be random but the pattern are there let me update question.

Comment: @Shadow is right you should not use SQL for this as the "swap" algorithm is much to "complex" in SQL to write/handle.. Also it would be to slow without indexes..  Especially if you don't use MySQL 8 and need to use co-related subqeuries to get access to other records value instead of MySQL 8 windows functions like `LEAD()` and `LAG()`

Comment: @daraptoor after seeing the updated pattern: forget sql, do this in application logic.

Comment: i believe their is a solution, i don't have any practical use for it. this question is asked  by someone so i am seeking the solution to it.

Comment: @daraptoor are there duplicate rows? Meaning the pair 11, 21 is unique?

Comment: *"i believe their is a solution"* it is "easy" when running MySQL 8 -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iLMafgzrw3x5R3puFMh4f6/0 .. i assume the order to be on X and that X is unique here otherwise the "groups" will mix up ideally the "group" information should also be stored in the table so you can you use `LEAD/LAG(swap.y) OVER(PARTITION BY group ORDER BY swap.x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work only if there are no duplicate rows:

```
update tablename t inner join (
  select 
    (@row_number1:=@row_number1 + 1) num, x, y
  from tablename, (select @row_number1:=0) t
) n  
on n.x = t.x and n.y = t.y
inner join (
  select 
    (@row_number2:=@row_number2 + 1) num, x, y
  from tablename, (select @row_number2:=0) t
) p 
on p.num = case n.num % 2 
  when 1 then n.num + 1 
  when 0 then n.num - 1
end  
set t.y = p.y;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qZgUGFU1H4Yi6qpZSe6Ds/0).
Results:

```
| x   | y   |
| --- | --- |
| 11  | 22  |
| 12  | 21  |
| 12  | 24  |
| 14  | 23  |
| 15  | 26  |
| 16  | 25  |
```

Comment: Amazing answer can you explain because I don't understand but it working perfectly.

Comment: @NavedKhan if you execute `  select (@row_number1:=@row_number1 + 1) num, x, y  from tablename, (select @row_number1:=0) t` alone you will see that it provides to the table a number starting from 1 for each row. This is needed to do the update because it is based on the order of the rows. So I join the table to that query twice. Once to match the values x and y and then to match the row number. The `on` clause at the end checks if the the row's number is even or odd so to match the previous or the next row.